# Получение MethodInfo для метода, импортированного из библиотеки dll

Tags: c#, dll, рефлексия

Из программы на С# с помощью генерации IL кода создаю сборку, в которой хочу сделать DllImport и воспользоваться функцией из библиотеки.
Как правильно задекларировать DllImport и вызов импортированного метода в сборке с точки зрения создания IL кода?

```
[DllImport("D:\\Dll2.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void ResCall(IntPtr ptr);
```

Comment: А собственно что не так? Сейчас у вас нормально задекларирована dllimport

Comment: @Aarnihauta, мне нужно сделать это с помощью генерации IL из С# или как-то получить MethodInfo на метод ResCall. Вот так это сделать не получается: typeof(IecLibraryBuilder).GetMethod(nameof(IecLibraryBuilder.ResCall))